# How to make Chrome allow http request to custom local domain?

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, cookies, https, hosts

I am creating a simple light/dark mode toggle in a `create-react-app`, with the following code in my `<App />` component:

```
  const [darkMode, setDarkMode] = useState<boolean>(() => {
    const storedDarkMode: string | undefined = Cookies.get('my_dark_mode');
    console.log(storedDarkMode);

    if (storedDarkMode !== undefined) {
      return JSON.parse(storedDarkMode);
    } else if (
      window.matchMedia &&
      window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)').matches
    ) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  });

  const toggleDarkMode = () => {
    setDarkMode((prev) => !prev);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (darkMode) {
      document.body.classList.add('dark-mode');
    } else {
      document.body.classList.remove('dark-mode');
    }
    Cookies.set('ap_dark_mode', JSON.stringify(darkMode), {
      domain: 'myname.dev',
    });
  }, [darkMode]);
```

I have the following in `/etc/hosts`:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost.myname.dev
```

(and I have executed `sudo dscacheutil -flushcache`, also restarted the computer, FWIW)

I have the following in my React project's `.env.development`:

```
HOST=localhost.myname.dev
PORT=3000
```

When I start the dev server via `npm run start`, I see the following:

```
Compiled successfully!

You can now view portfolio_v4 in the browser.

  http://localhost.myname.dev:3000

Note that the development build is not optimized.
To create a production build, use npm run build.

webpack compiled successfully
Files successfully emitted, waiting for typecheck results...
Issues checking in progress...
No issues found.
```

However, when I attempt to visit `http://localhost.myname.dev:3000`, Chrome converts the request to `https`.  I do not want to configure `https` right now, I just want Chrome to allow me to make an `http` request.

I have entered `localhost.myname.dev` into the `Delete` option found at `chrome://net-internals/#hsts` but that didn't work.  I've also tried clearing the browser cache.

EDIT:

You can see Chrome redirecting me to `https` here:
[image]

Comment: sorry to mention the obvious, but asking any way, just in case. Did you restart chrome after updating hsts setting?

Comment: @NazrulChowdhury yea, thanks for checking though